# Electrical issue Ford Flex

Tags: electrical, ford, troubleshooting, flex

Walked by my parked 2009 Flex in driveway. The radio was playing!!  I unlocked it, lo and behold, all the dashboard lights are flickering on and off, I can  move the shifter, the bell is dinging like the key is in the ignition, and the throttle body is clicking away like crazy under the hood. I had to disconnect battery to get it to stop.  Went and bought a new battery the next day (a hail mary), did not alleviate the problem.

The first shop couldn't get it to replicate so I picked it up, drove it to work, and it wouldnt start anymore, in addition to all the aforementioned problems.(Battery was not dead, good charge still)

Second shop diagnosed a bad smart junction box ($600 repair), car starts up great, problemseems to be solved,   but next day I walk by my car in driveway, and.... radio is playing!!  Same exact problem still happening.  Super sad face.

Any ideas as to what it could BE?

Comment: Have you had any water leaks?

Comment: Even if you haven't noticed a leak, has it been raining when it happens?

Comment: There has been a thunderstorm here or there, and I did take it through the car wash once, but there hasn't been a lot of rain and not in days.  Obviously the SJB wasn't the source of the problem, what else do you think it could be?  I kept suggesting ignition switch, as it behaves like the key is in the ignition at times, (able to shift ignition, bell dinging) but that doesn't explain throttle body clicking and dashboard lights flashing

Comment: So the  update is the electrical problems seem to be gone.  So I guess the smart junction box was the problem.  Or maybe it was wet somewhere, and dried out.  Now I'm afraid to wash my car.

Comment: So I took my Flex through an automatic car wash, after not washing it for a few weeks.  I park it for 2 hours, come out, guess freaking what.  I go to unlock my car and the radio is playing, the bell is dinging when I open the door, lights are flashing, the car won't start.  So I guess it is a moisture problem.  Had to get it towed.  SUPER SAD FACE!!!!!!

Comment: The car repair shop started it right up the next day, no  problem.  They couldn't get it to act up at all, even when they sprayed the engine down with a hose.  The checked the connectors and what not, nothing.  After three days I took it back home.  My 2009 Ford Flex is playing a clever game of cat and mouse, and winning.

Comment: Any more info on this. Mine is doing the same thing. Had to replace the battery. Thought that fixed it. Went out and radio was on. All dash lights as well.